# How to retrieve all permissions assigned to a group in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, permissions

I am working on a task to retrieve a set of permissions assigned to a group in Django and I can get the created groups using the below code, but could not use it to get the permissions assigned to them:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
groups = Group.objects.all()
```

I am not really sure how to get permissions assigned to these groups.

`permissions = Permission.objects.all()` gives me all the permissions, but I could not figure out how to get permissions assigned to a particular group.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

The `Group` model has a `ManyToMany` relationship with the `Permission` model, so you can do this

```
for group in Group.objects.all():
    permissions = group.permissions.all()
    # do something with the permissions
```

Comment: do not do query in loop! in this case better to do something like this `group_ids = Group.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True) 
Permission.objects.filter(group__id__in=group_ids)` this way u will always have only 2 queries.

Comment: Hey @SardorbekImomaliev can you throw some light on this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65156217/tests-for-checking-the-permissions-of-a-group

Answer (score 9):

To get all permissions in all groups the current user belongs to use this:

```py
all_permissions_in_groups = user.get_group_permissions()
```

To get all permissions related to a user including ones that are not in any group do this:

```py
all_permissions = user.get_all_permissions()
```

For more details see [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the name of the group, one way is:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
group_name = "test"

group_permissions = Group.objects.get(name=group_name).permissions.all()
```