# Check if Django Group has Permission

Tags: django

I am developing a Django website where I can create groups, where permissions can be assigned. I can also assign groups to users.
There is a simple way to check if a user has a permission:

```
user.has_perm('app_name.permission_code_name')
```

What I want to know is if there is a simple way to check if a specific group has a permission (without involving the user at all)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
for group in Group.objects.all():
    permissions = group.permissions.all()
    # do something with the permissions
```

Or, a better way would be:

```
group_ids = Group.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)  
Permission.objects.filter(group__id__in=group_ids)
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538672/how-to-retrieve-all-permissions-assigned-to-a-group-in-django) may be able to help you further.